# Starting a process as a user account

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

Currently I am working on an windows installer which has a custom action built in to run an installed exe immediately after installation.

My problem is that using System.Diagnostics.Process the application launches under the SYSTEM user when I would like the application to launch under the same user that is running the installer.

Is this possible?

Comment: Is that component a pre-requisite of your product? Then you might want to use a bootstrapper.

Answer (score 2):

You may use one of the [overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) of the [Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxf2saat.aspx) method which takes `username` and `password`.